# Launch front camera in Mobile Web app developed using C# Jquery

Tags: asp.net, iphone, asp.net-web-api, jquery-mobile

I want to launch front camera by default in a web browser for an ASP.NET web application developed using C# language and it uses jquery, HTML for UI. Now, it always open back camera by default. How to set and launch front camera? I am trying to run application in iPhone/Android mobile.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add what you've tried to your question so you don't get any repetitive answers?

Comment: I have tried following code snippet: <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="user"> 
Above line of code I have used to launch the camera.

Answer (score 0):

by this specification https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/
looks like currently make default to front camera it's not possible for security and privacy